# Check connectivity between On-Prem/Azure Servers and SQL database instances?

Tags: sql, powershell, azure-sql-database, ssms

Our BI team has a mixture of On-Prem and Azure servers that run scripts to execute SQL processes to other On-Prem and Azure SQL databases. Sometimes our processes errors out due to connectivity issues from and to the servers. I would like to write a script that checks from-to server connectivity before executing our ETL processes. What scripting approaches are ideal for this type of connectivity check?

We can ping to make sure computers are online, but we don't currently have a process to check connectivity between two servers. It seems like the issue is related to connectivity between on-prem and cloud servers. This could be due to firewall and network issues, but the issue occurs irregularly and could be due to a number of factors. Our current connection method is SQL Server Authentication. Are there other optimal ways to connect?

I would like to identify a good approach to script/monitor/check connectivity between a mix of on-prem/azure cloud servers and databases. Some example scripting would be great as well!

Answer (score 0):

To ping the servers, I use the **`Test-Connection`** cmdlet. In the definition of the Test-Connection command, I determine the buffer size, the number of pings to submit, and whether it returns detailed ping status information or a simple Boolean value. I specify the ea parameter (ea is an alias for the **`ErrorAction`** parameter) value of 0. The value of 0 tells the cmdlet to not display error information (an error displays when a ping is unsuccessful).

Here is how Pingtest will look like:

```
$servers = “dc1″,”dc3″,”sql1″,”wds1″,”ex1”

Foreach($s in $servers)

{

  if(!(Test-Connection -Cn $s -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet))

  {

   “Problem connecting to $s”

   “Flushing DNS”

   ipconfig /flushdns | out-null

   “Registering DNS”

   ipconfig /registerdns | out-null

  “doing a NSLookup for $s”

   nslookup $s

   “Re-pinging $s”

     if(!(Test-Connection -Cn $s -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet))

      {“Problem still exists in connecting to $s”}

       ELSE {“Resolved problem connecting to $s”} #end if

   } # end if

} # end foreach
```

By this way you can be sure that connectivity is live and you can proceed with execution.
Hope it helps.